# Retrieve Cookie From Akka HttpResponse

Tags: scala, cookies, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to retrieve a cookie from Akka HttpResponse

> val httpRequest = HttpRequest(method=HttpMethods.POST, uri = uri,
>   entity=params)
>       val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =  Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri))
>
> ```
> responseFuture2.flatMap { response =>
>   println(response.entity)
>   response.headers.collect {
>     case hc =>
>       println(hc)
>   }
> }
> ```

However I cannot find the cookie value in either response entity or response headers. I believe that the cookie jar should have been supported already in akka. 
https://github.com/spray/spray/pull/311

Does anyone has idea how can I retrieve the cookie by utilizing akka? Thanks in ad!

Here's how I've done it in python.

> cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar() non_redirecting_opener =
>   urllib2.build_opener(NoRedirectionProcessor,
>   urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)) response =
>   non_redirecting_opener.open(request) cookies = {cookie.name: cookie
>   for cookie in cookie_jar}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll do the trick:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers._

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http(context.system).singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:8080"))

responseFuture.onComplete(response => {
  val cookies = response.get.headers.collect {
    case c: `Set-Cookie` => c.cookie
  }
  println(cookies)
})
```

But you should not operate on Future directly but send it through actor system.